# Compare Count of record for the first and last of the month across a range of months in CRM Analytics

Tags: salesforce, report, analytics, crm, salesforce-einstein

We have a somewhat complicated report that we're trying to generate to find the headcount at the start of each month compared to the headcount of the end of each month across a range of months.

We have two objects, Contacts and Contact Status. The contact status will have records for each change of status between active and inactive.

I am struggling to find a way to accomplish this. I can get a list of all employees that were active for each month, but not counts of the first day and last day.

Is this possible with CRM Analytics? If so, what would I need to do to create this report?

We've created a LWC with a loop that finds the first and last day of each month, runs a SOQL query for both, and stores those values in a table. It works to a degree, but it uses a lot of queries, it's slow, and the UI/UX isn't great for the people using it. CRM Analytics works much better for all of the other reports, but this report has been very difficult.